# How to display filenames of word documents in a folder using python?

Tags: python, arrays, document, docx

I want to display the filenames of word document present in a specified path using python.

Comment: Use `os.listdir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this could work for you:

```
for file in os.listdir(PATH):
    if file.endswith(".doc") or file.endswith(".docx"):
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be just as simple as creating a custom iterator using `scandir` passing the file extension (for word documents you can use docx). Like this:

```py
import os
from typing import Type, Iterable


def scan_dir(path, file_ext) -> Iterable[Type[os.DirEntry]]:
    for dir_entry in os.scandir(path):
        if dir_entry.name.endswith(f'.{file_ext}'): yield dir_entry


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for word_doc in scan_dir('.', 'docx'):
        print(word_doc.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for @sxeros approach :)

```
import os

PATH = "your path"

files = list(filter(lambda s: ".doc" in s or ".docx" in s, os.listdir(PATH)))

print(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

### 1: `glob` with regular expression

The `glob` library is great for something like this ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)):

```
import os
from glob import glob

word_docs = glob(os.path.join(PATH, "*.doc*"))
```

### 2: conditional list concatenation

This does everything using `os` library alone:

```
import os

word_docs = [wd for wd in os.listdir(PATH) if wd.endswith(".docx") or wd.endswith(".doc")]
```